# Sms login Mesibo Messenger (Android)

Tags: android, sms, messenger, mesibo

I would like to use Mesibo Messenger.  I have my host, my database and my account but I need a guide just to finish the process.  I have already compiled the WhatsApp-type mesibo app from the GitHub link.  I would like to use and modify it for my project and be able to publish it on the Play Store.  Now my only concern is because in the value file there is the Facebook ID to log in but Facebook has already stopped giving access to its API for that. I know well that I am going to need another way to log in but I don't know which company offers this option And if I find one, my question is, do I just have to change the Facebook ID or do I just have to call MainActivity after generating the token?  It's just this part that leaves me a little confused .  If it were through Firebase it would be much easier for me but I don't know how to log in via SMS.

Do I need help achieving SMS login or can you refer me to a company that does it?